# How to define a dynamic struct "field"?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, arrays, struct

We have a `struct` as follows :

```
struct ObjectStruct {
        bytes32 state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;
    }
mapping(bytes32 => ObjectStruct) public objectStructs;
    bytes32[] public objectList;
```

Now, we want to modify `bytes32 state;` field such that it would be dynamic and so we would be able to "add" several "sub_state" to it, ex. `objectStructs[_object_id].state.location = _location;` or `objectStructs[_object_id].state.price= _price;` etc.

How we can define such a "dynamic state field" such that we would be able to add any "sub_state" to it ?

I defined it as follows:

```
struct ObjectStruct {
        bytes32 location;
        bytes32[] state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;
    }
```

And then :

```
function newObject(bytes32 _object_id, bytes32 _state, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_object_id));

        objectStructs[_object_id].state = _state;
        objectStructs[_object_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_object_id].isObject = true;
        objectList.push(_object_id);

        LogNewObject(msg.sender, _object_id, _state, _owner);
        return true;
    }

event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 _object_id, bytes32 state, address owner);
```

then, we invoke `function newObject` as follows :

```
newObject(100, "location:Paris,price:50,sold:yes", '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773');
```

I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a *'dynamic state field'* as you explain in your post. But you can use a mapping inside the struct that will do that for you.

```
struct StateStruct {
    bytes32 description;
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
}

struct ObjectStruct {
    StateStruct state;
    address owner; 
    bool isObject;
}
```

then use

```
objectStructs[id].state.sub_state["location"] = "Paris";
objectStructs[id].state.sub_state["sold"] = "Yes";
objectStructs[id].state.sub_state["price"] = 50;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response, but I did not understand exactly where "myState" in your "struct ObjectStruct" is defined ? Thanks

Comment: sorry is my typo, corrected now

Comment: Thanks again. Just could you please let me know by this struct, how to define "function newObject" and "event LogNewObject" parameters ? Thank you.

Comment: you need to define the parameters in the state as array `(bytes32[] states,bytes32[] state_values)` iterate through the array and store the substate `objectStructs[_object_id].state.sub_state[states[i]] = state_values[i]` the event can be changed passing the arrays as well instead of a single string (that's up to you actually).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it if you could let me know how to set value of "states" and "state_values" at time of invoking function? it's a bit complicated :) Thanks again

Comment: for example, newObject(100, {"location","sold","price"},{"Paris","Yes","50"}) is correct ? Thanks once again