# Error Encoding Argument (remix)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, arrays

We have a contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.23; 

    contract RFID {

        struct StateStruct {
            bytes32 description;
            mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
        }

        struct ObjectStruct {
            StateStruct state;
            address owner; 
            bool isObject;
        }

        mapping(bytes32 => ObjectStruct) objectStructs;
        bytes32[] public objectList;
        //uint256 public number_of_sub_states = 3;

        event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
        event LogChangeObjectState(address sender, bytes32 uid, bytes32 newState);
        event LogChangeObjectOwner(address sender, bytes32 uid, address newOwner);

        function isObject(bytes32 _id) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
            return objectStructs[_id].isObject;
        }

        function getObjectCount() public view returns(uint count) {
            return objectList.length;
        }

        /*function setArraySize(uint256 _number_of_sub_states) public {

            number_of_sub_states = _number_of_sub_states;

        }

        function getArraySize() view public returns (uint256) {
           return number_of_sub_states;
        }*/

        function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
            require(!isObject(_id));

            uint256 counter=0;
            for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

                objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

                emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, sub_states_types[counter], bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

            }

            objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
            objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

            objectList.push(_id);

            return true;
        }

        function changeObjectState(bytes32 _id, bytes32 _newState) public returns(bool success) {
            require(isObject(_id));
            //objectStructs[_id].location = _newState;
            objectStructs[_id].state = StateStruct(_newState);
            emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, _newState);
            return true;
        }

        function changeObjectOwner(bytes32 _uid, address _newOwner) public returns(bool success) {
            require(isObject(_uid));
            objectStructs[_uid].owner = _newOwner;
            emit LogChangeObjectOwner(msg.sender, _uid, _newOwner);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

When, I call `function newObject` in remix, I receive the following error:

Invoke newObject in remix using related text box : `100, 3,
 [bytes32("location"),bytes32("price"),bytes32("sold")], [bytes32("Paris"),bytes32("50"),bytes32("yes")], address(0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773)`

ERROR : `error encoding arguments syntax error unexpected token b in JSON at position 12.`

**What is the reason of this error ?**

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : I edited my question regarding to the answer of user Jesse Busman.

Answer (score 2):

I see four potential problems with your function call:

1. You should use square brackets `[]` for array literals instead of curly braces `{}`:

   ```
   newObject(100, 3, ["location","price","sold"], ["Paris","50","yes"], '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773');
   ```
2. The `newObject` function takes dynamically sized arrays as arguments.
   From the Solidity documentation:

   > Note that currently, fixed size memory arrays cannot be assigned to
   >   dynamically-sized memory arrays, i.e. the following is not possible:
   >
   > ```
   > // This will not compile.
   >
   > pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
   >
   > contract C {
   >     function f() public {
   >         // The next line creates a type error because uint[3] memory
   >         // cannot be converted to uint[] memory.
   >         uint[] x = [uint(1), 3, 4];
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   One solution is to change the function signature of `newObject` to accept only arrays of size 3:

   ```
   ..., uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[3] sub_states_types, bytes32[3] sub_states_values, ...
   ```
3. An array literal of strings cannot be implicitly converted to an array of `bytes32`. You can cast the values in the function call manually:

   ```
   newObject(100, 3, [bytes32("location"),bytes32("price"),bytes32("sold")], [bytes32("Paris"),bytes32("50"),bytes32("yes")], '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773');
   ```
4. Addresses in Solidity are written as hexadecimal constants casted to 
   `address`. So you should write this: `address(0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773)`

   instead of this: `'0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Concerning number 2 i.e. "dynamically  sized array" I used this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47529/how-to-define-a-dynamic-struct-field/47531?noredirect=1#comment56142_47531   So, is there a problem in his answer ?

Comment: I proposed a solution for number 2 here :https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47542/setting-values-of-an-byte-array-dynamically Do you agree with this solution ?

Comment: I modified my question regarding your answer. Now we have another problem at time of invoking newObject function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I must invoke newObject function in remix in following format:

```
40,3,["location","price","sold","","","","","","",""],["Paris","50","No","","","","","","",""], 0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773
```

Now, the result is true.